# Working with a function of geometric Brownian motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes

I am a novice in stochastic calculus, so apologies if the following question is naive. Suppose $P_t$ follows a geometric Brownian motion
$$
 d P_t = \mu P_t dt + \sigma P_t dB_t\ ,
$$
where $B_t$ is Brownian motion. I wish to define a process that involves $P_t$ in its integrated form, e.g.
$$
 d W_t = (\rho W_t + P_t) dt\ .
$$
The motivation is that $P_t$ could be some stochastic pay-off that is continuously added to a wealth process $W_t$ that is otherwise simply growing deterministically at rate $\rho$. I have two questions:

1. What sort of process is $W_t$?
2. Can it be approximated by an Ito diffusion?
3. Could I have chosen $P_t$ differently such that $(\rho W_t + P_t) dt$ becomes an Ito diffusion?

Re Q1: Given some initial condition $P_0$ for $P_t$, we can write
$$
 d W_t = (\rho W_t + P_0 \exp{[(\mu - \sigma^2/2)t + \sigma B_t]} )dt\ ,
$$
which doesn't look like an Ito diffusion to me. Do such processes have a name? Have they been studied in the literture?

Re Q2: Some of the proof techniques I am trying to imitate in the optimal-stopping literature rely on $W_t$ being an Ito process. Is there any way to approximate $W_t$ as such?

Re Q3: I am open to ditching the GBM assumption on $P_t$ if an alternate assumption would allow me to write $W_t$ as an Ito diffusion, but I can't see any clean way to do this. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can you get your hands on Roy Howard's : "A signal theoretical introduction to random processes". It's not a finance text but he does give an example of how the lebesgue stieltjes integral can be used to calculate the dollar gain on a stock. Let $f(t)$ be the number of shares held at time $t$ and let  $B_t$ be a brownian motion representing the stock price. Then, $\int_{[0,T]} f(t) dB(t)$ will calculate the gain in dollars up until time $T$.  He doesn't go into so many details ( not so many more than I gave here ) but it's an interesting way to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an ODE $y'=f(x)y(x)+g(x)$ with solution

$$y=ce^{\int fdx}+e^{\int fdx}\left(\int g(x)e^{-\int f dx}dx \right)$$

and so

$$W_{t}=ce^{\rho t}+e^{\rho t}\left(\int^{t} P_{s}e^{-\rho s}ds \right).$$

If you want the law of integrated Geometric Brownian motion $P_{s}$ see ["On Some Exponential Functionals of Brownian Motion."](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1427477).

Comment: Thanks for this. Would you be able to provide more detail on questions 1, 2, 3 in the OP? I'm interested in understanding more about the relationship between $W_t$ and Ito processes.

Comment: $W_{t}$ is not a diffusion because it has no Brownian motion volatility term. In terms of approximation, the difficulty will be in approximating the integrated. Geometric Brownian motion, which is a common object in finance.